# Link between div and p tags

Tags: php, wordpress, html, hyperlink

This is code:

```
    $variableName = Test;
echo ' <div class="navigation"> <p> '.next_posts_link($variableName).' </p> </div>';
```

And the result in browser is:

```
<a href="example.com/">Test</a>; <div class="navigation"> <p> </p> </div>
```

How can I put the link between div and p tags?

Comment: What's wrong with you? You already have the answer to this question in your exact same previous question and the other question which is basically the same!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser reads php code as text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111669/browser-reads-php-code-as-text)

Comment: That problem was resolve, now we have another one. Code is OK, but link is not between div and p tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next_posts_link()` echos out the text; you're expecting it to return a string. So it's appearing in the wrong place in your output when you try and concatenate its output.

You need to split the call up:

```
echo ' <div class="navigation"> <p> ';
next_posts_link($variableName);
echo' </p> </div>';
```

Alternatively, `get_next_posts_link()` returns a string:

```
echo ' <div class="navigation"> <p> '.get_next_posts_link($variableName).' </p> </div>';
```

Comment: You're welcome. It can be quite hard to figure out the right function to use in WordPress, but the documentation is _excellent_.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no need of enclosing **next_posts_link** function inside php open close tags. You may try the following:

```
echo '<div class="navigation"><p>'.next_posts_link($variableName).'</p></div>';
```